# Multiple division in algebra and expressing as powers

Tags: linear-algebra

I can’t really find any resources on this so if you have some please let me know, but I suppose it’s really specific I only need to know this for units.

---

If you have the following:

$$
p=\frac{x}{\dfrac{y}{q\cdot \frac{1}{z}}}
$$

Is this how you’d write them in powers?:

$$
p=x\cdot y^{-1}\cdot q^{-2}\cdot z^{-3}
$$

---

I think I’m wrong because when I see units written in this way it doesn’t seem to happen like that.

Comment: Because q is time under y so -2 and z is 1 time under q so -3 that’s the ‘logic’ I’m using @matthewtowers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in saying that what you have is incorrect. Note that $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}} \ne \frac{1}{x^2}= x^{-2}$. In fact, $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}} = x = x^1$.

Now to your problem: Let's simplify the above fraction by taking the bottom fraction and instead of dividing by it, we are going to multiply by its reciprocol: $$p=\frac{x}{\frac{y}{q*\frac{1}{z}}}$$ $$ = x * (\frac{q*\frac{1}{z}}{y})$$
Next, let's move the $z$ fraction out from the bigger fraction,
$$ = x * \frac{q}{y}* \frac{1}{z}$$
Finally, we decompose again, by knowing that $\frac{a}{b} = a * \frac{1}{b}$, give it a little more notation and we get
$$ = x * q * \frac{1}{y}*\frac{1}{z}$$ $$ = x^1*q^1*y^{-1}*z^{-1}$$

Comment: Thank you, I didn’t know I had to take that into account (that the way I wrote it could be simplified), I guess I could’ve avoided this problem by writing it more simplified in the first place @veryVerde

Comment: Having a fraction as a denominator can be confusing. Best to just flip it, to simplify to a single fraction before deciding to do anything with it.

Comment: how it it so obvious for you and everyone else that?: $$\dfrac{x}{\dfrac{y}{z}}=x\cdot (\frac{z}{y})$$

Comment: I get that: $$\frac{1}{x}=x$$ but don’t understand why that’s the case, I think that’s why this isn’t obvious to me @michalburgunder

Comment: Because that is how divisions of fractions work. It's something most of us have learned in elementary school, so any explanation of the problem has less to do with modern math and more to do with math pedagogy, which is why no one explains it. I'm not sure if I can help you understand this concept in a short paragraph. However, this site has a *basic* overview: https://www.mathsisfun.com/fractions_division.html

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{x}{\dfrac{y}{q\cdot\dfrac{1}{z}}} = \dfrac{x\cdot q\cdot\dfrac{1}{z}}{y} = \dfrac{xq}{zy}$$.